# filter log file by defining regexes

Tags: java, regex, linux, logging, grep

I have some HUGE log files (50Mb; ~500K lines) I need to start filtering some of the crap out of.  The log files are being produced using log4j and have the basic pattern of:

```
[log-level] date-time class etc, etc  
log-message
```

I'm looking for a way that I can identify a regex start and regex end (or something similar) that will filter out the matching entries from the file so I can more easily wade through these massive files.  My thoughts are that the start regex would be the log-level and the end regex would be something in the log-message.  I'm sure I could write a java program to accomplish this task, but I thought I'd ask the community before going down that path.  Thanks in advance.

---

Let me expand on my question.  Let's assume I have the following snippet in my log file:

```
[DEBUG] date-time class etc, etc  
log-message-1

[WARN] date-time class etc, etc  
log-message-2

[DEBUG] date-time class etc, etc  
log-message-3

[DEBUG] date-time class etc, etc  
log-message-1

[WARN] date-time class etc, etc  
log-message-2

[DEBUG] date-time class etc, etc  
log-message-6
```

I'd like a way to filter out logEntry1 and logEntry2 so I end up with:

```
[DEBUG] date-time class etc, etc  
log-message-3

[DEBUG] date-time class etc, etc  
log-message-6
```

I would hope to accomplish this be defining some sets of regex patterns pairs.  In my example above, I'd want to define a pair for logEntry1 and another for logEntry2.

I hope that helps clarify my question.

Comment: It would be good to add a more concrete example. What are the possibilities for [log-level]? How can you tell when the log-message lines are finished and another item starts? Help us to help you. Smells like gawk or perl, but need more info.

Comment: log-level values: DEBUG, INFO, WARN, ERROR, FATAL

log-messages are finished when another log-level is encountered.

Comment: for the record, 50mb isn't really that huge.

Comment: Yeah, real trouble starts over 1 Gig :-)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Assuming `log-message-1` and `log-message-2` and unique patterns.

```
$ awk -vRS= '!/log-message-[12]/' ORS="\n\n" file
[DEBUG] date-time class etc, etc
log-message-3

[DEBUG] date-time class etc, etc
log-message-6
```

Comment: I'm not sure I understand what this is doing.  This doesn't specify the start regex.

I did notice that this trimmed out all blank lines from my log.

Comment: I still don't understand what this is doing, but it seems to be working.  I believe I can take this snippet, define my set of regexes in a file, read the file, loop over each regex executing your snippet, and I should be there.

Comment: the command set the record separator to blank lines, so each block from `[..]` to the blank line is considered 1 record. then the pattern search for records that DON'T have the words `log-message-1` or `log-message-2` and print them out. That's all there is.

Answer (score 1):

```
(zyx:~) % echo $T
[DEBUG] date-time class etc, etc  
log-message-1

[WARN] date-time class etc, etc  
log-message-2

[DEBUG] date-time class etc, etc  
log-message-3

[DEBUG] date-time class etc, etc  
log-message-1

[WARN] date-time class etc, etc  
log-message-2

[DEBUG] date-time class etc, etc  
log-message-6
(zyx:~) % echo $T | perl -e '$_=join("", <>); s/\[DEBUG\][^\n]*\n(log-message-1|log-message-2).*?(?=\n\[(DEBUG|WARN)\]|$)//sg; s/\[WARN\].*?(?=\n\[(DEBUG|WARN)\]|$)//sg; print;'


[DEBUG] date-time class etc, etc  
log-message-3



[DEBUG] date-time class etc, etc  
log-message-6
```

Comment: no-no-no. please, dont' create multigb strings in perl with `$_=join("", <>);`

Comment: Author said he has 50 MiB file. If he said about 2 GiB file, I would have written other script.

Answer (score -1):

Use `awk` or awk-styled perl one-liners.

Comment: sure sure... assuming I'm a awk or perl expert, which I'm not

Comment: awk is VERY easy to learn. You need a little of awk to parse such files.

perl can be used in the same awk-style with easy syntax.